# Удаление <br> в коде

Tags: обсуждение

Нужно ли удалять `<br>` в блоках кода?

```
Вот как это <br>
выглядит, <br>
т.е. я вынужден переносить строку с помощью [Enter], никакие "<br>" <br>
тут не помогают.
```

[Пример текста](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1189822/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0) (уже исправлен, но это не отменяет сути вопроса).

---

Меня интересует не возможность так писать, а именно то, приемлемо это или нет.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вопрос немного странный, как мне кажется. Насколько я понимаю, наличие `<br>` в исходном сообщении было обусловлено тем, что ТС просто не был в курсе, как нужно оформлять код. Он оформил его обычным текстом и для перевода строк, добавил эти `<br>`.

Когда код оформили как код, безусловно необходимость в этих `<br>` отпала. Поэтому, конечно, писать так не надо, достаточно просто оформлять код доступными на сайте средствами, а не изобретать какое-то кустарное форматирование.

Comment: ну не знаю, странным мне кажется замечание от aleksandr barakin, где я исправил `"\\[\\\\some\\]"` на `@"\[\\some]\"`, а он меня штрафанул, отклонив правку. подумал, что и за такое могут штрафануть по причине, мол, вы не понимаете того, что автор хотел сказать

Comment: @return к сожаление, ничего не знаю про случай с `some`. Однако, вам до 2К осталось немного репы добрать и можно будет без утверждений правки вносить.